# Specifying more than one drl directories in changeset.xml

Tags: java, drools, drools-fusion

```
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set.xsd' >
<add>
<resource source='file:/opt/rulesRepository' type='DRL'>
</resource>
</add>
<add>
<resource source='file:/opt/systemRules' type='DRL'>
</resource>
</add>
</change-set>
```

Currently using drools 5.1.1 .If i try to configure more than one directory with drls using changeset.I observed that the only the last directory is getting scanned by drools.
Is this behaviour is correct?
My requirement is that i need to configure more than one drl directories.Please provide me some pointers to resolve the issue in case if there is any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

After below changes it started working.

```
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set.xsd' >
<add>
<resource source='file:/opt/rulesRepository' type='DRL'>
</resource>
<resource source='file:/opt/systemRules' type='DRL'>
</resource>
</add>
</change-set>
```